# How to change UIImageView image on previous and next button click

Tags: iphone

I have an NSMutableArray with 10 different images. Initially I am displaying first three images from that array. Now What I want is to display next images from that array, when the next button click. Also previous images when previous button is clicked. I am able to display different images when next button gets clicked, But it comes only on the last UIImageView.

```
- (IBAction)nextImage:(id)sender { 
    NSLog(@"count is :%d%d",count,courseArry.count); 
    if ((count+1) > courseArry.count) {
        count = 0; 
    }
    starImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[courseArry objectAtIndex:count]];
    count++;
}

-(IBAction)previousImage:(id)sender {
   if ((count-1) > courseArry.count) { 
      count = 0;
   }
   starImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[courseArry objectAtIndex:count]];
   count++; 
}
```

Comment: What exactly the problem is? May be show your code so we won't need to guess

Comment: - (IBAction)nextImage:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"count is :%d%d",count,courseArry.count);
    if ((count+1) > courseArry.count) {
        count = 0;
    }
    starImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[courseArry objectAtIndex:count]];
    count++;
}

-(IBAction)previousImage:(id)sender
{
    if ((count-1) > courseArry.count) {
        count = 0;
    }
    starImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[courseArry objectAtIndex:count]];
    count++;
}

Comment: I have made a UIImageView dynamically as i don't know how many number of images will be in the array. Initially I am displaying top 3 images from that array in the UIImageView. I also have two button named ad next and previous buttons. On clicking the next button it will display the fourth image from that array, similarly on clicking the previous button it will display previous image.

Comment: Now what i want is that on clicking the next button the first image should be replaced by the second one and second image should be replaced by the third image and so on.